# Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription With Sessions - Queue Length

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have a topic subscription with sessions that I cannot manage to get the queue length down on. It appears to keep within a constant range of 95 to 105, very tightly.

I am wondering if this is just an artefact of sessions, as our other subscription of this same topic, without sessions, managed to sit below 10 easily.

The message rate is not particularly high, at around a constant 50 per second.

There are currently 102 long lived sessions. Each session will see 1 message every 2 seconds. Over time more sessions will be created as we add new "channels".

The best explanation I can muster is that, while the subscription queue length is around 100, when you normalise it for the number of sessions, it effectively zero's it out.

Could this be expected behaviour when working with sessions in an topic subscription?

Comment: How do you get message counts for your subscription? Are you using Azure Monitor service?